# Read line by line in a txt file, if there is overwrite if there isnt that sentence append to the file

Tags: c, csv, fgets

I have a txt file

```
[what]
apple = apple is fruits

[who]
steve = steve is a teacher
```

I am suppose to read the file and if the input is equal to the lines, it will overwrite. If there isnt then it will append to a new line.

below is my codes

```
    char lines[255];
    char question[255];
    char answer[255];
    FILE* f;

    if ((f = fopen("text.file", "a")) == NULL) {
        printf("File not found");
        exit(1);
    }
    scanf("%s", &question);

    while (fgets(lines,255,f)!= NULL) {
        if (lines != question) {
            printf("I dont know. %s", question);
            scanf("%s", &answer);
            fputs(answer, f);
        }
    }
    fclose(f);
```

I tried running , and it just doesnt go through  the if statement. Why ist so ?

Answer (score 1):

Add `#include <string.h>` and replace `if (lines != question)`

for `if (strcmp(lines, question) != 0)`.

Comment: I already added <string.h> 
is there another solution other than strcmp?

Comment: You can always make your own strcmp.

Answer (score 0):

You can't compare strings with this:
     if (lines != question)
Replace with this:
if(strncmp(question,question,strlen(question))!=0)